# How do I run some javascript after a CSS transition on a pseudo element in MS Edge?

Tags: css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11, pseudo-element, microsoft-edge

I'm having trouble handling the "transitionend" event in Microsoft Edge, **on a pseudo element**.

It works in other browsers like chrome, safari, and firefox. I thought it may have been a bug with MS Edge, but it doesn't work in IE11 either, so maybe there is some other way that I'm missing in the Microsoft world.

Does anyone know how to handle this in IE?

Here's the code... the box will turn green after the fade-in completes if the transitionend event has been handled correctly.

```js
window.setTimeout(function(){
  
  $('#box').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd',function(){
    $(this).addClass('done');
  });
  
  $('#box').addClass('show');
  
},1);
```

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
}
#box:before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
}
#box.show:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
#box.done:before {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#box {
  position: relative;
}
#box > .before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
}
#box.show > .before {
  opacity: 1;
}
#box.done > .before {
  background-color: green;
}
```

IE11 has an issue with transitionend on pseudo element. If added extra elements inside the parent container. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Is you used jQuery's .animate() function, you can have a function put on the end to be run, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#box').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
    $('#box').animate({background-color: green}, 1000);
  });
});
```

The background-color will only transition to green after it has finished fading in. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for animating properties on pseudo elements like :before. I'm using pseudo elements in my real project so that I can fade background images with default images underneath, and tints/gradients over the top.